# how to solve this factorial

Tags: python, factorial

I've managed to get factors in a list but I can't finish because I'm doing something wrong in the end, the count variable is not updating with the products.
I want to solve it without using the factorial function.

Question:
Write a program which can compute the factorial of a given number.
The results should be printed in a comma-separated sequence on a single line.
Suppose the following input is supplied to the program:
8
Then, the output should be:
40320

Hints:
In case of input data being supplied to the question, it should be assumed to be a console input.

```
user = int(input("Input a number: "))
factors = []


while user > 0:
    n = user * (user - 1)
    if user == 1:
        factors.append(1)
        break
    else:
        factors.append(user)
        user -= 1

count = 0   # this should be updating but it's not 
for f in range(factors[0]):  # I'm not sure if this is the correct range
    counting = factors[f] * factors[f + 1] # I'm not sure about this either
    count = count + counting 
    f = f + 1
```

Comment: Are you confusing [factors](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/factors) and [factorials](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/factorial?s=t)? Because it really looks like you are.

Comment: Factorial is not a complicated program. It can be written in one line.

Comment: they mean the output of a factorial, for example the result of a factorial 8 is 40320

Comment: why bother with having a list of factors? Start with a default product of 1 and, in a loop, repeatedly multiply that product by the various factors. No need to store the factors.

Comment: factors is just a name I've given to a list, I used that list to capture the products that the factorial consists of

Comment: You don't need extra storage. You need a for-loop.

Comment: Am I missing something here? `def f(n): return n*f(n-1) if n > 1 else 1`... no?

Comment: sure, but I didn't want to use a function

Comment: @noob81 okay, gotcha. A loop, then.

Comment: @JohnColeman can you write that down please? I'm not sure what "default product of 1" should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the last part of your program to:

```
result = 1
for f in factors:
    result *= f

print result
```

Comment: amazingly simple and yet so invisible, that's exactly what I wanted but my brain tends to complicate things

Answer (score 0):

Finding the factorial of a number is simple. I'm no python expert, and it could probably be written simpler but,

```
    def factorial(n):
      if n == 0:
         return 1
      else:
         return n * factorial(n-1)
```

I think @erip may be right in the comment section.

Comment: This is inefficient. Avoid recursion when possible.

Comment: This is true, but for the likes, of what seems to be a homework problem, I thought that the shortest/simplest answer would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input("Input a number: "))

factorial = 1

for i in range(2,num+1): # range isn't inclusive
   factorial*=i
```